# Error when trying to render component in react-testing-library - got an object

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm trying to setup some integration tests of some react components that are connected to our redux store.

Our general pattern is a const (instead of a component) which is "connect"ed with redux to the store (I think this is just background to the issue, as I have the same problem with a normal component).

I am following https://testing-library.com/docs/example-react-redux

I get this error

```
   console.error node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:172
      Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

  Check your code at feedback.test.js:32.
console.error node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:19814
  The above error occurred in the <Provider> component:
      in Provider (at feedback.test.js:26)
```

This is my test

```
import React from 'react';
import {createStore} from 'redux'
import {Provider} from 'react-redux'
import {render, getByTitle, fireEvent} from '@testing-library/react'
//import '@testing-library/cleanup-after-each'
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect'

import {FeedbackContainer} from '../feedbackContainer'
import {defaultState, reducer} from '../../../../redux/modules/feedback'

function renderWithRedux(
  component,
  {
    initalState, store = createStore(reducer, defaultState)
  } = {}
) {
  return {
    ...render(<Provider store={store}>{component}</Provider>)
  }
}

it('increments the counter', () => {
  console.log(<FeedbackContainer/>)
  const {container} = renderWithRedux(<FeedbackContainer />) <-- line 32
})
```

My container component looks like this:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Feedback } from './feedback';
import { compose, lifecycle, withHandlers } from 'recompose';
import { actions } from '../../../redux/modules/feedback';

export const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => ({
// snipped state maps
});

export const mapDispatchToProps = {
// snipped functions
};

const enhance = compose(
  connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps),
  withHandlers({
    sendFeedbackHandler: props => () => props.sendFeedback(props),
    handleResize: props => () => props.setWindowSize(),
  }),
  lifecycle({
    componentDidMount() {
      const {handleResize} = this.props
      window.addEventListener('resize',handleResize);
    },
    componentWillUnmount() {
      this.props.clearFeedback();
      const {handleResize} = this.props
      window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize);
    },
  }),
);

export const FeedbackContainer = enhance(Feedback);
```

The feedback.js looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactStars from 'react-stars';

export const Feedback = (props) => {

    const ratingChanged = (rating) => {
      props.setRating(rating);
    }

    const {sendFeedbackHandler} = props

    var title = null;
    switch (props.type) {
      case "REF":
        title = "Rate this FAQ"
        break;
      default:
        title = "Rate my experience"
        break
    }

    var feebackLayout;
    var buttonClassNames = "btn btn-success btn-cons pull-right";
    if (props.apertureWidth > 768) {
      buttonClassNames += " margin-right-0px ";
      feebackLayout = (
        <div>
          <h5 className="light semi-bold text-center" style={{"margin":"0px"}}>
            {title}
          </h5>
          <div style={{"textAlign":"center"}}>
            <div data-test-id='feedback-stars' className="center" style={{"display":"inline-block","float":"none"}}>
              <ReactStars
                value={props.rating}
                count={5}
                onChange={ratingChanged}
                size={24}
                color2={'#ffd700'}
                half={false}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      )
    } else {
      buttonClassNames += " margin-right-14px ";
      title = "Rate this:"
      feebackLayout = (
        <div style={{"textAlign":"center"}}>
          <h5 className="light semi-bold text-center"
           style={{"margin":"0px","display":"inline","verticalAlign":"middle","paddingRight":"10px"}}>
            {title}
          </h5>
          <div style={{"textAlign":"center","display":"inline-block","verticalAlign":"middle"}}>
            <ReactStars
              value={props.rating}
              count={5}
              onChange={ratingChanged}
              size={24}
              color2={'#ffd700'}
              half={false}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      )
    }

    return (
      <div className="card card-default feedbackCard" style={{"height": "100%","borderTopRightRadius": "2px", "borderTopLeftRadius": "2px"}}>
        <div className="card-block" style={{padding: '20px 20px 20px 20px'}}>
          <div hidden={props.feedbackSubmitted}>
            {feebackLayout}
            <div hidden={props.feedbackHidden}
             style={{"paddingTop": props.apertureWidth > 768 ? "0px" : "10px"}}>
              <div>
                <textarea
                  data-test-id='feedback-text'
                  className="form-control"
                  style={{"height":"unset"}}
                  placeholder="Add any comments"
                  rows={2}
                  onChange={event => props.setFeedback(event.target.value)}
                />
              </div>
              <div style={{paddingTop: "5px"}}>
                <button
                  data-test-id='feedback-submit'
                  className={buttonClassNames}
                  onClick={sendFeedbackHandler}
                >
                  {props.buttonText}
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div hidden={!props.feedbackSubmitted}>
            <h5 className="light semi-bold text-center">
              {props.feedbackSubmittedMessage}
            </h5>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
};
```

If I change my test to use the underlying Feedback component rather than the container it doesn't crash (but then I don't think the store will be correctly connected as mapstatetoprops isn't going to be called.

If I console.log the components in my test they both return objects from what I can see so I don't quite understand the error.

FeedbackContainer:

```
{ '$$typeof': Symbol(react.element),
        type:
         { mapStateToProps: [Function],
           mapDispatchToProps: [Function: mapDispatchToProps],
           reactComponent: { [Function: WithHandlers] displayName: 'withHandlers(lifecycle(Component))' },
           mockDispatch:
            { [Function: mockConstructor]
              _isMockFunction: true,
              getMockImplementation: [Function],
              mock: [Getter/Setter],
              mockClear: [Function],
              mockReset: [Function],
              mockReturnValueOnce: [Function],
              mockReturnValue: [Function],
              mockImplementationOnce: [Function],
              mockImplementation: [Function],
              mockReturnThis: [Function],
              mockRestore: [Function] } },
        key: null,
        ref: null,
        props: {},
        _owner: null,
        _store: {} }
```

Feedback:

```
{ '$$typeof': Symbol(react.element),
        type: [Function],
        key: null,
        ref: null,
        props: {},
        _owner: null,
        _store: {} }
```

From some reading I think this could be down to some version compatabilites, this is what I have in my package.json:

```
"jest": "^21.2.1",
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.1.0",
"@testing-library/react": "^9.1.4",
"react": "^16.8.6",
"react-dom": "^16.0.0",
"react-redux": "^5.0.5",
"redux": "^3.7.2",
"redux-saga": "^0.15.6",
```

Where am I going wrong?!

Comment: It looks like `Feedback` is returning an object. Maybe you can try to debug it to figure out why

Comment: @mattb can you share the source for `Feedback` too?

Comment: With the following versions, your code seems to work for me:
`"jest": "^24.7.1",
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.1.0",
"@testing-library/react": "^9.1.4",
"react": "^16.8.6",
"react-dom": "^16.8.6",
"react-redux": "^7.1.1",
"redux": "^4.0.1",`

Comment: @skovy - edited my post. thanks

Comment: So as @GiorgioPolvara-Gpx suggested the problem is I'm getting an object, I think I've narrowed this down to my FeedbackContainer using recompose.compose to make a HOC. Is there something I can do to make @testing-library/react.render accept this?

Comment: RTL should not care what you're using to render your components. In the end, it's just going to ask React to render whatever you pass and then interact with the result. I think your problem is in the components rather than in RTL

Comment: but if my component can be displayed in a browser it must be a valid component surely?

Comment: Hi. I know its been 2 years. But, has anyone figured out how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Please see my answer here: [What is wrong with react-testing-library render function? It returns an error on certain objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57962228/what-is-wrong-with-react-testing-library-render-function-it-returns-an-error-on/71078520#71078520)

```
expect(() =>
        render(
            <AddAssessmentFormModal
                recordDetailView={<RaDeathDecisionEditView />}
                addRecord={(record: any) => addAssessment(record)}
            />,
            {
                wrapper: () => <AppWrapper store={store} />,
            }
        )
    ).not.toThrow();
```