# What is wrong with react-testing-library render function? It returns an error on certain objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, jestjs, react-testing-library

Using:     "@testing-library/react": "^9.1.4",

If I call:

render({component})

Where component is:

```
{ '$$typeof': Symbol(react.element),
        type:
         { mapStateToProps: [Function],
           mapDispatchToProps: [Function: mapDispatchToProps],
           reactComponent: { [Function: WithHandlers] displayName: 'withHandlers(lifecycle(Component))' },
           mockDispatch:
            { [Function: mockConstructor]
              _isMockFunction: true,
              getMockImplementation: [Function],
              mock: [Getter/Setter],
              mockClear: [Function],
              mockReset: [Function],
              mockReturnValueOnce: [Function],
              mockReturnValue: [Function],
              mockImplementationOnce: [Function],
              mockImplementation: [Function],
              mockReturnThis: [Function],
              mockRestore: [Function] } },
        key: null,
        ref: null,
        props: {},
        _owner: null,
        _store: {} }
```

I get this error:

> console.error node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:172
>         Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite
>   components) but got: object.

If I render this component there is no error:

```
{ '$$typeof': Symbol(react.element),
        type: [Function],
        key: null,
        ref: null,
        props: {},
        _owner: null,
        _store: {} }
```

They both appear to be react.elements and https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/api implies this is what it expects.

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `render({component})`, according to the docs the input should be `React.ReactElement<any>`.

Have you tried `render(component)`?

Comment: thanks for the comment, looks like I lost some formatting on my orginal post, I'm calling render like this:
render(<Provider store={store}>{component}</Provider>)
Where {component} is passed to the function

Does my console output of Symbol(react.element) not show its a React.ReactElement<any> ?

Comment: Can you provide the full source of the test?

Comment: if you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57959972/error-when-trying-to-render-component-in-react-testing-library-got-an-object I gave the full detail, I just thought it was a bit too long winded for anyone to read!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by doing the following:

```
expect(() =>
        render(
            <MyFormModal
                recordDetailView={<MyFormEditView />}
                addRecord={(record: any) => addMyRecord(record)}
            />,
            {
                wrapper: () => <MyAppWrapperWithRedux store={store} />,
            }
        )
    ).not.toThrow();
```

The render() function in RTL takes a second parameter where you can specify your wrapper that connects to the redux store. Ofcourse, this is assuming your issue was caused by a wrapping component, and that you are using redux.